# PHP Form does not submit into $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I cannot use the $_POST function to value my inputs.

On my HTML page, I want to write the values of inputs distributed in different tables into the $_POST as soon as a submit button is pressed.

The reason why I use different tables is that it seemed to me to be the easiest way to create responsive structures.

I hope that the different tables are not the problem here, otherwise I would have to rewrite everything.

Here the structure of the Html page:
[image]
My complete code for the  follows here:

```
<form method="POST">
                <div class="inner_div">
                    <table width=100% border=0 /*style='display: none;'*/>
                            <tr>
                                <td width=15%>Datum:</td>
                                <td width=1%><div class='add_main_div' align='center'><input type=button value='&#9776;' style='font-size:15px;' class='add_main' name='list_datum' id='buttonlist_datum' title='Listenaufruf: Datum'><div></td>
                                <td><input type='date' name='time_head_date' <?php if(isset($time_head_date)){ echo "value='$time_head_date'";} ?>></td>
                                <td><input type='submit' name='submit_datum' value='OK'></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table border=0>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=3><h2 style='margin-bottom:-15px;'>Arbeitszeitprofile:<h2></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=5%>Kann:</td>
                            <td width=1%><div class='add_main_div' align='center'><input type=button value='&#9776;' style='font-size:15px;' class='add_main' name='buttonlist_kannprofil' id='buttonlist_kannprofil' title='Listenaufruf: Datum'><img src='images/list_icon.png' width=80%></button><div></td>
                            <td width=15%><input type=number name='time_head_kannprofil' <?php if(isset($time_head_kannprofil)){ echo "value='$time_head_kannprofil'";} ?>></td>
                            <td><input type=text name='number_kann_arbeitszeitprofil' <?php if(isset($time_head_kannprofil_bez)){ echo "value='$time_head_kannprofil_bez'";} ?> disabled></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=5%>Soll:</td>
                            <td width=1%><div class='add_main_div' align='center'><input type=button value='&#9776;' style='font-size:15px;' class='add_main' name='buttonlist_sollprofil' id='buttonlist_sollprofil' title='Listenaufruf: Datum'><img src='images/list_icon.png' width=80%></button><div></td>
                            <td width=15%><input type=number name='time_head_pflichtprofil' <?php if(isset($time_head_pflichtprofil)){ echo "value='$time_head_pflichtprofil'";} ?>></td>
                            <td><input type=text name='number_kann_arbeitszeitprofil' <?php if(isset($time_head_pflichtprofil_bez)){ echo "value='$time_head_pflichtprofil_bez'";} ?> disabled></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width=100% border=0 /*style='display: none;'*/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><hr></td>
                            <td align=center width=5% ><div class='add_main_div' align='center'><input type=button value='+' id='add_main_time' class='add_main' name='add_main'><div></td>
                            <td><hr></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width=100% border=0 <?php if(!isset($_POST['add_main'])){echo "style='display: none;'";} ?>>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=inherit><h2 style='margin-bottom:-5px;'>Zeitraum hinzufügen:</h2></td>
                            <td width=1%><div class='add_main_div' align='center'><input type=button value='&#9776;' style='font-size:15px;' class='add_main' name='buttonlist_zeitposten' id='buttonlist_zeitposten' title='Listenaufruf: Datum'><img src='images/list_icon.png' width=80%></button><div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width=100% border=0 <?php if(!isset($_POST['add_main'])){echo "style='display: none;'";} ?>>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align=center>von</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align=center>bis</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=20%></td>
                            <td align=center><input type='time' class='time_big' name='time_posten_von' <?php if(isset($time_posten_von)){ echo "value='$time_posten_von'";} ?>></td>
                            <td align=center width=15%>-</td>
                            <td align=center><input type='time' class='time_big' name='time_posten_bis' <?php if(isset($time_posten_bis)){ echo "value='$time_posten_bis'";} ?>></td>
                            <td width=20%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width=100% border=0 <?php if(!isset($_POST['add_main'])){echo "style='display: none;'";} ?>>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=10%>Buchungsart:</td>
                            <td width=1%><div class='add_main_div' align='center'><input type=button value='&#9776;' style='font-size:15px;' class='add_main' name='list_soll'  title='Listenaufruf: Datum'><img src='images/list_icon.png' width=80%></button><div></td>
                            <td width=15%><input type=text name='time_posten_buchungsart' <?php if(isset($time_posten_buchungsart)){ echo "value='$time_posten_buchungsart'";} ?>></td>
                            <td><input type=text name='number_kann_arbeitszeitprofil' disabled></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=5><input type='submit' value='Speichern' name='save_all'></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div> <!--inner_div-->
                </form>
```

All input type=text/number should be evaluable.

The evaluation of $_POST currently only takes place via `<?php print_r($_POST);?>`

Does anyone know what my mistake is?

Comment: What is the `HTTP Content-Type` in the request?

Comment: If I stick that code into a PHP file and add a `var_dump($_POST)` at the top, when I click on "OK" it shows the form values I entered.

Comment: tables is really _not_ the way to go with responsive design. Tables are for tabular data, not for layout. People used to use tables for layout in the 1990s when CSS was not very good. You will not find any responsive design tutorial or guide which suggests using tables. You can make a responsive form properly using CSS and divs, it is perfectly possible

Comment: Anyway we have no idea what's wrong with your PHP because you didn't show it to us, or really explain the problem very clearly. We don't know what "I can't" means - show the code you used, and explain what happens when you use it. You said "the evaluation of $_POST currently only takes place via <?php print_r($_POST);?>"...what does that mean? Do you see the submitted values when you print that, or not? Give a clear description. Your form itself looks ok - the fact you've used tables in the HTML has no impact on how the form data is submitted to the server.

Comment: @droopsnoot @ADyson @Swatantra KumarMany thanks for the quick feedback.
@droopsnoot After inserting `var_dump($_POST)` above my code, I could at least briefly see the full array output. After that I knew that the array was reset by a new page request.
@ADyson you're right, of course, that tables don't allow for a really responsive layout, but it serves my purposes very well here. Since I have limited knowledge of CSS, this was the easiest solution. The solution was, as already written, a page call at every call. But thanks for the help.